# Excel macro take values from vector to populate matrix

Tags: excel, vba, vector, matrix

I'm not sure if this title is descriptive enough.

So basically I have a number of vectors (about 50 of them), each containing several hundred values. Each vector is labelled with a number, and they look something like this:

```
Vector 1
Stim1     12
Stim5     36
Stim7     24
Stim10    4
...       ...
```

That is, they have a number associated with a specific stimulus label (StimX). However, each vector is populated by a unique set of stimulus labels; some stimulus labels are shared between multiple vectors - however, each vector does not contain every stimulus label, and no one stimulus label is shared by every vector. So, for example, Vector 2 would look like this:

```
Vector 2
Stim2     28
Stim3     33
Stim5     9
Stim8     40
...       ...
```

and

```
Vector 3
Stim4    50
Stim3    10
Stim7    4
Stim11   22
...      ...
```

Furthermore, each vector has a variable number of values ... some have 200, others 300, etc.

What I want to do is create a macro that will populate a matrix based on these vector values. So the matrix would look something like:

```
        Vector 1      Vector 2      Vector 3    ...
Stim1      12
Stim2                    28
Stim3                    33            10
Stim4                                  50
Stim5      36            9
Stim6
Stim7      24                          4
Stim8                    40
Stim9
Stim10     4
Stim11                                 22
...
```

I don't really know VBA that well, so I am sure this can be  done pretty simply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have assumed that your Vector and Stim list in sheet1, and sheet2 will display your matrix.

Column A - vectors and stims 
Column B - corresponding #s

This code will do the job:

```
Option Explicit

Sub cMatrix()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim cnt As Long
    cnt = 2
    Dim tmp As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim arr() As String

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)

    ' populate Y axis: list of stims
    For i = 1 To ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If StrComp(CStr(Left(ws1.Range("A" & i), 1)), "s", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            ws2.Range("A" & cnt).Value = ws1.Range("A" & i).Value
            cnt = cnt + 1
        End If
    Next i

    ' populate X axis: vectors
    cnt = 2
    For i = 1 To ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If StrComp(CStr(Left(ws1.Range("A" & i), 1)), "v", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            ws2.Cells(1, cnt).Value = ws1.Range("A" & i).Value
            cnt = cnt + 1
        End If
    Next i

    ' fill array
    ReDim arr(ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1)
    For i = 2 To ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        arr(i - 2) = ws2.Range("A" & i).Value
        ws2.Range("A" & i).ClearContents
    Next i

    ' remove duplicate
    Call RemoveDuplicate(arr)

    ' reprint stims
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        ws2.Range("A" & i + 2).Value = arr(i)
    Next i

    ' fill matrix
    For cnt = 2 To ws2.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For i = 1 To ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            If StrComp(ws2.Cells(1, cnt).Value, ws1.Range("A" & i).Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                j = i + 1
                While StrComp(Left(ws1.Range("A" & j).Value, 1), "S", vbTextCompare) = 0
                    For tmp = 2 To ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                        If (StrComp(ws2.Range("A" & tmp).Value, ws1.Range("A" & j).Value, vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
                            ws2.Cells(tmp, cnt).Value = ws1.Range("B" & j).Value
                            j = j + 1
                        End If
                    Next tmp
                Wend
            End If
        Next i
    Next cnt

End Sub


Public Sub RemoveDuplicate(ByRef StringArray() As String)
    Dim LowBound As Long, UpBound As Long
    Dim TempArray() As String, Cur As Long
    Dim A As Long, B As Long
    If (Not StringArray) = True Then Exit Sub
    LowBound = LBound(StringArray)
    UpBound = UBound(StringArray)
    ReDim TempArray(LowBound To UpBound)
    Cur = LowBound
    TempArray(Cur) = StringArray(LowBound)
    For A = LowBound + 1 To UpBound
        For B = LowBound To Cur
            If LenB(TempArray(B)) = LenB(StringArray(A)) Then
                If InStrB(1, StringArray(A), TempArray(B), vbBinaryCompare) = 1 Then Exit For
            End If
        Next B
        If B > Cur Then Cur = B: TempArray(Cur) = StringArray(A)
    Next A
    ReDim Preserve TempArray(LowBound To Cur)
    StringArray = TempArray
End Sub
```

If you have any questions, please ask!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! At a cursory glance it looks pretty good. Unfortunately serendipity is not with me today; I am having computer troubles with the machine that has the data on it, so it might be a day or two before I can really verify this. Just running it on some made up data in Excel and it seems to work just fine.

Comment: Great! Remember to run this on a copy of your source data at first. Good luck